# Как перевести текст в нужный язык (забыл переключить клавиатуру и напечатал другим языком)

Tags: java, строки, клавиатура

> Создайте класс KeyboardSwitch. Его конструктор принимает строку и внутри него происходит: Перевод текста в нужный язык (забыл переключить клавиатуру и напечатал другим языком).

Помогите решить

```
public class KeyboardSwitch {
    String str;

    KeyboardSwitch(String str) {

        char[] ch1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        char[] ch2 = {'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'ч', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я'};

        String arr[] = str.split(" ");

        
    }
}
```

Comment: на чем именно застрял? Включи на клавиатуре другой язык и набери текст. Как ты его будешь переводить в правильный?

Comment: Можете использовать в данном случае словарь, где key - русские символы и value английские. Проходите циклом и таким образом замененяете

Comment: Что за дикое задание реализовывать весь функционал в конструкторе?  Чего вы хотите добиться, разбивая строку по пробелам?  Приходилось ли вам видеть тексты, набранные в неправильно включённой раскладке?

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи.**  В данном вопросе такая попытка не просматривается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, речь идёт о том, что надо заменить неправильную раскладку клавиатуры (например: `ghbdtn` на `привет`).

Тогда вот вам алгоритм:

1. Создаёте 2 массива типа char. В первом будет содержаться буквы того языка, в который надо перевести, а во втором — символы из английской раскладки. Индексы символов с одной и той же клавиши должны совпадать. То есть как-то так:

```java
char[] RU = {'а', 'б', 'в', ...}; //И так до я
char[] EN = {'f', ',', 'd', ...}; //И так далее
```

Ведь на русской клавише <kbd>а</kbd> находится символ <kbd>f</kbd>,  на русской <kbd>б</kbd> - <kbd>,</kbd>, на русской <kbd>в</kbd> - <kbd>d</kbd> и так далее.

2. Делаете замену в цикле c помощью метода [`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) в классе `String`:

```java
str = str.replace(EN[i], RU[i]);
```

В примере `str` — строка, `i` — переменная в цикле `for`.

**P.S**: делать это всё в конструкторе глупо. Конструктор конструирует объект, а не выполняет какие-то другие действия. Для вашей цели подойдёт статический метод:

```java
public static String replaceIncorrectKeyboardLayout(String s) {
    //Реализация
}
```

Comment: поздравляю с вхождением в клуб!  У вас появился анонимный поклонник-минусатор!

Comment: Такое событие следует отметить плюсом. :)

Comment: @NowhereMan ага. Мне не повезло: у меня минуса только на 2 ответа, было бы на три, тогда бы откатились :(

Comment: Всё-таки это серьёзное упущение в системе, что разрешены хейтерские анонимные минусы на ответах.  Здесь явно какому-то "учителю по жизни" показалось, что _низзя_ зарабатывать карму на такого рода вопросах, а он в свою очередь ничего никому объяснять не должен.  И он явно знаком с тем как работает система, чтобы избежать отката своего голосования.

Comment: @NowhereMan они запрещены. И если их больше 3, то они даже откатываются. "Смягчить" критерии для определения хейтерства нельзя: ведь 2 минуса на сообщения одного автора - вполне легальная ситуация. А насчёт комментирования минусов - есть [топик на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/532877). Не случайно тот вопрос - самый дублируемый на мете за всё время её существования (22 дубликата). Вот мне нравится [этот ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10456/532877) в качестве утешения.

Comment: Может я неправиьно выразился -- не разрешены, а допускаются системой, которой в принципе дела особо нет, что _если_ имеется возможность безнаказанно "вредить" чьей-то репутации, то этим обязательно воспользуются именно с целью нанесения вреда, а не с какими-то благими намерениями.

Comment: Просто мой ответ на данный вопрос, в котором я детально расписал более оптимальное решение для замены символов, также заработало минус, за компанию с вашим :)

Answer (score 0):

Как верно отметил Зонтик в постскриптуме [своего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1546594/386633), для решения данной учебной задачи хорошо подходят обычные статические методы, принимающие и возвращающие строку, таким образом, класс `KeyboardSwitch` станет *утилитарным* и не будет  необходимости создавать его экземпляры.

Однако предложенная реализация с итерацией *по всем символам* алфавита и вызовами методов `String::replace(char oldC, char newC)` не слишком оптимальна, из-за пересоздания экземпляров строки.  Гораздо эффективнее было бы проитерироваться по символам входной строки и заменить каждый символ через таблицу соответствий с использованием `StringBuilder`.

Таблица соответствий может быть реализована как с помощью мапы (в том числе и двунаправленной [BiMap](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) из библиотеки Guava), так и с помощью оператора `switch`.
Второй способ лучше подходит для новичков.

Вариант реализации транслятора русской раскладки в английскую (только для букв).

Итерация по символам входной строки происходит в методе `convert`, который также принимает в качестве аргумента ссылку на метод перекодировки символов `Function<Character, Character>`.

```java
public class KeyboardSwitch {
    public static String ruToEn(String str) {
        return convert(str, KeyboardSwitch::ruToEn); // ссылка на метод перекодировки
    }
    
    private static String convert(String str, Function<Character, Character> fromTo) {
        if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
            return str;
        }
        int n = str.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n); // зарезервировать емкость как у начальной строки
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sb.append(fromTo.apply(str.charAt(i))); // добавить перекодированный символ, вызвав соответствующий метод
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static char ruToEn(char c) {
        boolean upper = Character.isUpperCase(c);
        char letter = switch (Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
            case 'ф' -> 'a'; case 'и' -> 'b'; case 'с' -> 'c'; case 'в' -> 'd'; case 'у' -> 'e'; case 'а' -> 'f';
            case 'п' -> 'g'; case 'р' -> 'h'; case 'ш' -> 'i'; case 'о' -> 'j'; case 'л' -> 'k'; case 'д' -> 'l';
            case 'ь' -> 'm'; case 'т' -> 'n'; case 'щ' -> 'o'; case 'з' -> 'p'; case 'й' -> 'q'; case 'к' -> 'r';
            case 'ы' -> 's'; case 'е' -> 't'; case 'г' -> 'u'; case 'м' -> 'v'; case 'ц' -> 'w'; case 'ч' -> 'x';
            case 'н' -> 'y'; case 'я' -> 'z';
            default -> c;
        };
        return upper ? Character.toUpperCase(letter) : letter;
    }
}
```

Соответственно, для перекодировки английской раскладки в русскую будут два следующих метода `enToRu`.  При перекодировке символов учитывается, что некоторые русские буквы (б, ё, ж, х, ъ, э, ю) находятся на клавишах с символами.

```java
public static String enToRu(String str) {
    return convert(str, KeyboardSwitch::enToRu);
}

private static char enToRu(char c) {
    boolean upper = Character.isUpperCase(c);
    char letter = switch (Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
        case 'f' -> 'а'; case ',' -> 'б'; case 'd' -> 'в'; case 'u' -> 'г'; case 'l' -> 'д'; case 't' -> 'е';
        case '`' -> 'ё'; case ';' -> 'ж'; case 'p' -> 'з'; case 'b' -> 'и'; case 'q' -> 'й'; case 'r' -> 'к';
        case 'k' -> 'л'; case 'v' -> 'м'; case 'y' -> 'н'; case 'j' -> 'о'; case 'g' -> 'п'; case 'h' -> 'р';
        case 'c' -> 'с'; case 'n' -> 'т'; case 'e' -> 'у'; case 'a' -> 'ф'; case '[' -> 'х'; case 'w' -> 'ц';
        case 'x' -> 'ч'; case 'i' -> 'ш'; case 'o' -> 'щ'; case ']' -> 'ъ'; case 's' -> 'ы'; case 'm' -> 'ь';
        case '\'' -> 'э'; case '.' -> 'ю'; case 'z' -> 'я';
        case '<' -> 'Б'; case '~' -> 'Ё'; case ':' -> 'Ж'; case '{' -> 'Х'; case '}' -> 'Ъ'; case '"' -> 'Э';  
        case '>' -> 'Ю'; 
        default -> c;
    };
    return upper ? Character.toUpperCase(letter) : letter;
}
```

Тест для двух известных панграмм:

```java
System.out.println(KeyboardSwitch.ruToEn("Еру Йгшсл Икщцт Ащч огьзы щмук ф дфян вщп!"));
System.out.println(KeyboardSwitch.enToRu("C]tim to` 'nb[ vzurb[ ahfywepcrb[ ,ekjr b dsgtq xf.! <K>P} ~:\"{"));
```

Результат:

```java
The Quick Brown Fox jumps over a lazy dog!
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок и выпей чаю! БЛЮЗЪ ЁЖЭХ
```

Comment: Очередной анонимный бессловесный минус, без каких-либо претензий к ответу, хе-хе